# Routing issue when published Serenity Project to IIS but runs fine under kestrel

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, navigation

after publishing on IIS its base address is not include in navigation that causes error:

Navigation.cs :
[assembly: NavigationMenu(int.MaxValue, "AMSDB", icon: "fa-laptop")]
[assembly: NavigationLink(int.MaxValue, "AMSDB/Category", typeof(MyPages.CategoryController), icon: null)]

Serenity : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLWtz.png)https://github.com/serenity-is/Serenity

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. what is your error message?

Comment: please see the attached image. navigaiton skipping the appname

Comment: Does your url have anything to do with the A tag?

Comment: Yes brother url should be SereneAMS/AMSDB/Categegory insread of /AMSDB/Categegory it omitting the base url of app